# Creating many communication instances in socket programming in c++ linux

Tags: linux, multithreading, sockets

I have created one application with server and client class which have methods for creating either creating a tcp socket or udp socket. Now my requirement is i have created two application instances of this application. Since application is in c++ in unix environment I am using putty software to run the application. I have opened two instances of putty. But now my requirement is as follows:

There can be multiple communication instances between the 2 application instances

- Each communication instance, There can be multiple communication instances between the 2 application instances
- Each communication instance, can be either UDP or TCP (determined from the config file)be either UDP or TCP (determined from the config fil

Anybody who knows how to create such multiple instances.

Comment: One more thing since application is reading from config file so multiple instances created from single instance of this application can create both server and client.

Comment: I don't understand what you want, you have 2 instances of your application running and you want to communicate between them? that's what you want? is the TWO instances on the same machines or on different machines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm, so there are two processes, but they want the processes to be able to communicate with each other via more than one pair of sockets?  i.e. you could have two (or more) TCP socket connections between the two processes, and/or two (or more) pairs of UDP sockets sending packets back and forth.

If my above paragraph is correct (i.e. if I haven't misunderstood the request), that is certainly possible, although it's not terribly obvious what advantage you'd gain by doing it.  Nevertheless, what you'd need to do is have each instance of your application create multiple sockets (either by socket()+bind() for a UDP socket, or by socket()+bind()+listen()+accept() for accepting an incoming TCP connection, or by socket()+connect() to initiate a TCP connection to the other program instance.

The tricky part with managing multiple sockets is handling the waiting correctly.  With just one socket you can often get away with using the default blocking I/O semantics, and that way you can end up treating the socket something like a file, and just let each send() or recv() operation (etc) take however long it needs to take to complete before it returns to your calling function.

With more than one socket, on the other hand, you typically want to be able to respond to data on any of the sockets that are ready, which means that you can't just block waiting on any one particular socket, because if you do that, you may end up stuck waiting for a long time (potentially forever!) before that blocking call returns, and in the meantime you are unable to handle any data coming in from any of the other sockets.  (The problem becomes particularly obvious when one of the connections is to a computer whose plug was just pulled, as it will typically take the TCP stack several minutes to figure out that the remote computer has gone away)

To deal with the problem, you'll typically want to either use non-blocking I/O and a socket-multiplexing call (e.g. poll() or select() or kqueue()), or spawn multiple threads and let each thread handle a single socket.  Neither approach is particularly easy -- the socket-multiplexing approach works well once you get the hang of it, but the multiplexing calls' semantics are somewhat complex, and it takes a while to understand fully how it is intended to work.  Non-blocking I/O complicates things further, since it means your code has to correctly deal with partial reads and writes.  The multithreading approach seems simpler at first, but it has its own much larger and more subtle set of 'gotchas' (race conditions, deadlocks) that can cause much pain in the long run if you aren't very careful about what the threads are doing and how.

ps Since you're in a Unix environment, a third possible approach would be to fork() a child process for each socket.  This would be similar to the multithreading approach, except a bit safer since your "threads" would actually be processes and each would have their own separate memory space, and thus they'd be less likely to trip over each other while doing their work.  The downside would be higher memory usage, and also it becomes a bit harder (and slower) for the processes to communicate with each other due to the process space separation.

Comment: Thanks .. Nice explanation .. I have implemented this using multithreading .. will try my hand on other methods also .